# ajax extensions not working if asp.net project opened from sln

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010

I have an asp.net application and ive added some ajax scripts and update panels.

Problem is they are not working if i open the project from sln. If i open them from open website menu option in vs 2010 then they are working. But its creating some unnecessary sln files.

What is the correct way to work with asp.net project, open from sln or open as website in vs2010?

How can i get the updatepanel and scriptmanager to work? ive already a googled a lot and tried various responses already given. None seems to work.